# jQuery onClick on link element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose I have some code like so:

```
<a href="www.foobar.com" class="special-click">
   Content here
</a>

$( ".special-click" ).click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // Do other stuff
});
```

Assuming that the jQuery library is loaded, is my jQuery guaranteed to run before the page transitions? In other words, is it guaranteed that in the above example the user will never be taken to www.foobar.com?  If not, is there a way that I can add that behavior without adding an html onclick attribute?

Comment: Yes, it is guaranteed - unless there is a previous handler which prevents event propagation(immediate )

Comment: It is guaranteed but if you don't want to use `onclick` then you can replace `href`attribute value with `#`

Comment: According to https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/:
If this method **event.preventDefault()** is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qng6u7fh/

Comment: Your question is actually 2 different questions. 1) Is jQuery guaranteed to run before the page transitions? And 2) Is it guaranteed the user will never be taken to the next URL? The answer to #2 is no, it is not guaranteed as the user might have Javascript disabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be guaranteed then block this click event code inside $(document).ready(function() {      });

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".special-click").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("test")
        });

 });  
</script>
</head>
<body>

 <a href="www.foobar.com" class="special-click">
   Content here
</a>

</body>
</html>
```